# How to get the buildDir of a subproject in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

In `gradle.build` you can reference the `buildDir` and use it as a source or destination. How can I reference the `buildDir` of a subproject from the root `build.gradle` file?

(And a similar supplementary question, how can I reference subprojects in a Copy task? I have tried ':subproject_name/some_directory' but it errors).

Answer (score 26):

```
project(':a-subproject').buildDir
```

Answer (score 7):

In my root project's settings.gradle file, I specify the subprojects by name:

```
rootProject.name = 'my-root-project'
include 'subproject1', 'subproject2'
```

And then, in my build.gradle file, I can reference them by prefixing it with a colon:

```
project(':subproject1').buildDir
```